# Unique problem facing installing Ubuntu 14.04 alongside preinstalled windows 8.1 on laptop lenovo z7080

Tags: wireless, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I have recently buy lenovo z7080 laptop which has windows 8.1 pre-installed. I updated all the drivers and started to dual boot alongside windows with ubuntu 14.04LTS using dvd. I did enable legacy settings and give priority to legacy first. After when i entered into the installation i choose install ubuntu 14.04 alongside windows and after that give ubuntu about 750 gb and rest of about 250 gb to windows. But from entering the cd to start installation process my screen was shaking and linux could not find any wifi connection automatically and even when i manually tried.

After installation the the shake in the screen is still on and there is no internet connection(wifi). I did not tried lan connection.

While go back to windows through selecting UEFI from bios everything is ok there and size is altogether about 250 gb

Now how can i solve the ubuntu prob in screen shaking and auto internet connection??

Comment: my laptop has dedicated graphics card nvidia 840m and 16 gb ram

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) We're sorry but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum but a Question&Answer site: It works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer.  When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas which becomes more unlikely the more questions you put into... well, one question!  ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Comment: as mentioned earlier now i did not get the internet connection or wifi connection after install ubuntu? so how can i get that

Comment: Run the [wireless debugging script](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425205#425205) first and post the results to http://paste.Ubuntu.com

Comment: possible duplicate of [My wifi Qualcomm Atheros Device \[168c:0041\] (rev 20) doesn't show up and work in Ubuntu14.04.3 on lennovo flex 3 14](http://askubuntu.com/questions/678145/my-wifi-qualcomm-atheros-device-168c0041-rev-20-doesnt-show-up-and-work-in)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the WiFi is because the version of `ath10k` drivers shipped with ubuntu don't yet have support for the new `168c:0041` wireless card in the laptop. This is fixed in the 4.3 kernel. There's a 4.3-rc3 build available in the `kernel-ppa` ppa at http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.3-rc3-unstable/